# HowTo tell Express to ignore OPTIONS requests?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am using Express 4 and Node.js with Angular.js.

CORS has been a PITA so far.

At the moment I am seeing an OPTIONS request triggering my routes in express and then a POST request triggering my routes. Thus everything is triggered twice.

I am using cors in my api.js properly:

```
var cors               = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

However not only do my `POST` routes get hit twice with CORS as described above, also I am not able to `POST` from anything not on my localhost. I finally need to get this fixed. Any help is appreciated.

#### Route Functions

A typical route of mine:

```
var find = function(req, res, next) {

   return DOC.findById(req.body.id, function(err, doc) {

      if(!doc) {
        res.status(404).send({
          status: 'Not Found'
        });
      } else if (!err) {
        res.status(200).send({
          status: 'OK',
          doc:doc
        });
      } else {
        res.status(500).send({
          status: 'Server Error'
        });
      };
    });
  };
```

#### Hack

I am currently working around this annoyance with this ugly hack:

```
if (req.body.id === undefined) {

  console.log("[Exception] OPTIONS/CORS");
  res.status(304).send('Not Modified');

} else {
  ...
```

#### Routes Setup

```
app.get (...);
app.get (...);
app.put (...);
app.post ('/path/', expressJwt({secret:secret}), find);
app.delete (...);
app.post (...);
app.get (...);
```

In Firebug I am seeing:

`..Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows..`

Comment: How are you setting your routes?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking.  You don't actually want OPTIONS requests to be ignored - they are an essential part of CORS.  I'm not sure what your problem is but it's not in the 2 lines of code you shared with us.

Comment: But how do you set the route? What do you do with the variable "find"?

Comment: `find` is a function. Routes are set like in my update above. `find` gets called by the API CALL `app.post to /path/`

Comment: You don't want to ignore options requests, you want to [respond to them properly](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight).

Comment: Thanks for the link. What would be a proper response to the OPTIONS request? In my case I would have said it would be a good idea discarding them and sending them to hell, because I see absolutely no need for them, except giving me a massive headache. But this maybe a naive perspective. It is said Express 4 deals with this on its own but that saying was proven wrong.